# Demarcation of numbers and strings from stdin

Tags: c

I want to know if it is possible to demarcation numbers and characters from standard input.
In my case, I know the text will be not-fixed-size.

For example, I want to read from keyboard `READ REGISTER A` (using <s>`gets()`</s> `fgets()`), with `strcmp` to choose through a switch statement what case I am referring to.
But the problem is that when I write `WRITE REGISTER A 0x002`, I must `strcmp` the string `WRITE REGISTER A` and 
write to the register the value (0x002). I can't `strcmp` it because the value is not fixed.
The input that I give has other formats sometimes (e.g INITIALIZE, RESET, etc).

I know that with `sscanf` I can pull out the argument (hexadecimal) but I can't `strcmp` it.

How should I handle this?

Comment: Sounds like you want to parse the string into different components ("WRITE", "REGISTER", "A", and "0x002" in this case) using something like `strtok()`, and then process them

Comment: In other words, it's better to first check if you have a 'WRITE', then if you do, check whether it's a 'REGISTER', and if it is, check which register it is, and then you'll know to expect a number as the final token. That way, you don't have to separately check for 'WRITE REGISTER A', then 'WRITE REGISTER B', then "WRITE SOMETHING ELSE', etc.

Comment: And don't use `gets()`, since (1) it's bad; and (2) C11 actually finally got rid of it, so it's not C anymore.

Comment: Note that you won't be able to use a `switch` statement with `strcmp()` meaningfully for two reasons: (1) the cases in a switch statement must be compile-time constants, and (2) the return value from `strcmp()` is insufficiently well defined, having just three states (less than zero, equal to zero, or greater than zero).  The 'less than' value could be any number from -1 downwards, and the 'greater than' number could be any number from +1 upwards.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest avoiding `scanf()` at all costs, and using `strtok()` or similar:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSIZE 1000

int main(void) {
    char buffer[MAXSIZE];
    char * token;
    int n = 1;

    puts("Enter your command:");
    if ( fgets(buffer, MAXSIZE, stdin) == NULL ) {
        fputs("Error getting input", stderr);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    token = strtok(buffer, " ");
    while ( token ) {
        printf("Token %d is %s\n", n++, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Obviously you'll want to process the individual tokens in some way, or store them for later processing. You can `strcmp()` the individual tokens to check whether you have a 'WRITE', or a 'REGISTER', or whatever, and then turn the last one into a number with `strtol()`.

Here's a full working example, a simple left-to-right parse is often not appropriate, but it'll demonstrate a working technique (EDIT: added some better error handling):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXSIZE 1000

static long register_a = 0;
static long register_b = 0;
static const char * token_delims = " \r\n\t";

static void inst_write(void);
static void inst_write_register(void);
static void inst_write_register_n(long * p_register);
static void error_quit(const char * msg);

int main(void) {
    char buffer[MAXSIZE];
    char * token;

    /* Get input */

    puts("Enter your command:");
    if ( fgets(buffer, MAXSIZE, stdin) == NULL ) {
        error_quit("couldn't get input");
    }

    /* Tokenize and parse first token */

    token = strtok(buffer, token_delims);
    if ( token == NULL ) {
        error_quit("no instruction specified");
    }
    else if ( strcmp(token, "WRITE") == 0 ) {
        inst_write();
    }
    else if ( strcmp(token, "READ") == 0 ) {

        /* Check for other instructions like this */
    }
    else {
        error_quit("unrecognized instruction");
    }

    /* Output register contents */

    printf("Register A contains: %ld\n", register_a);
    printf("Register B contains: %ld\n", register_b);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

/* Processes a WRITE instruction */

void inst_write(void) {
    char * token = strtok(NULL, token_delims);

    if ( token == NULL ) {
        error_quit("missing WRITE operand");
    }
    else if ( strcmp(token, "REGISTER") == 0 ) {
        inst_write_register();
    }
    else if ( strcmp(token, "MEMLOC") == 0 ) {

        /* Check for other things to which to write */

    }
    else {
        error_quit("unrecognized WRITE operand");
    }
}

/* Processes a WRITE REGISTER instruction */

void inst_write_register(void) {
    char * token = strtok(NULL, token_delims);

    if ( token == NULL ) {
        error_quit("missing WRITE REGISTER operand");
    }
    else if ( strcmp(token, "A") == 0 ) {
        inst_write_register_n(&register_a);
    }
    else if ( strcmp(token, "B") == 0 ) {

        /* Check for other registers to which to write */

        inst_write_register_n(&register_b);
    }
    else {
        error_quit("unrecognized register");
    }
}

/* Processes the operand of a WRITE REGISTER [X] instruction, and
 * stores it in the appropriate register.
 *
 * Arguments:
 *   p_register -- pointer to the register in which to store
 */

void inst_write_register_n(long * p_register) {
    char * token = strtok(NULL, token_delims);

    if ( token == NULL ) {
        error_quit("missing WRITE REGISTER [X] operand");
    }
    else {
        char * endptr;
        long n = strtol(token, &endptr, 16);

        if ( endptr == token ) {
            error_quit("WRITE REGISTER [X] operand should be a hex integer");
        }
        else {
            *p_register = n;
        }
    }
}

/* General error handler, prints the supplied message and exit()s */

void error_quit(const char * msg) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: This approach is nice too, using `fgets` (providing that MAXSIZE is large enough) and tokenizing the in input into its parts.

Comment: `MAXSIZE` will always be large enough to avoid illegal writes when using `fgets()`, but yes, if someone types in an instruction greater than 1,000 characters long, they're going to get error messages.

Comment: From one evil (`scanf()`) to another (`strtok()`)...in context, `strtok()` might be the lesser evil, but it is not a routine I'd recommend.  The primary problem is that it tramples over the delimiter, thus making it impossible to tell what it was (which begins to matter if the language starts to use parentheses, etc).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It's not the beginnings of a general purpose parsing library, for sure, but it solves this type of simple problem in a non-evil and straightforward way.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths with 1000 it is less unlikely than with my `buf[64]` ;-)

Comment: Thanks a lot i cannot vote you because i need to have 15 Reputation.. sorry for that.

Comment: @user2221231: You can accept the answer (i.e. click the checkmark) if it was helpful to you, rather than voting, you have enough reputation for that.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have a set of commands, `READ`, `WRITE`, `RESET` etc. which your program has to recognize and accordingly perform some actions.

You'll need to parse the input by reading each of its parts one by one and depending on user input execute the commands.

Here is a basic set up for doing it:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include<stdlib.h> 
#include<string.h> 


void clear_stdin()
{
    int c;
    while((c = fgetc(stdin)) != '\n' && c != EOF)
        ;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)  
{ 
    char buf[64];
    char reg[10];
    unsigned int val = 0;
    int r = 0;

    do{
        printf("\nEnter a command: ");
        scanf("%s", buf);
        if(strcmp(buf, "WRITE") == 0) {
            scanf("%s", buf); // read away "REGISTER"
            scanf("%s", reg); // read name of REGISTER
            r = scanf("%x", &val);
            if(r == 1) {
                printf("write %i to register %s\n", val, reg);
            } else {
                scanf("%s", buf);
                printf("input is not valid: %s\n", buf);
            }
        } else if(strcmp(buf, "READ") == 0) {
            // TODO
        } else if(strcmp(buf, "RESET") == 0) {
            // TODO
        } else if(strcmp(buf, "exit") == 0) {
            break;
        } else {
            printf("Unknown command: %s\n", buf);
        }
        clear_stdin();
    } while(1);

    printf("Bye!\n");

    return 0;  
}
```

**Sample input**

```
WRITE REGISTER A 0xFF
```

**Output**

```
write 255 to register A
```

You may use `scanf("%s", buf);` and pass `buf` to [strtol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol) instead of `scanf("%x", &val)` for converting a hex number from string to long.

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` gives you undefined behavior, the behavior of `fflush()` is only defined by the C standard (and POSIX) for output and update streams.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Yes, you're right, that was quick and dirty, `fflush` should be used only for output streams. For not spreading bad/wrong stuff, I replaced it with an alternative. Thanks for pointing that!